# Javascript - handling 3gb of data for regular calculations

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, large-files, bigdata

I am currently thinking about the layout of a feature for our app and since this is by far the heaviest part, I am not sure how to design it:

We want users to give the possibility to backtest their assumptions against a large dataset.

- The dataset is over 3gb large (json)
- It has to be preprocessed (format needs to be changed) before usable for calculations
- It could be split in smaller files as the topics within the large dataset are separable.

In the beginning I thought I read the entire file in our store and work from there. I am just starting to doubt the memory will survive that (what kind of consumption to assume, running on aws).

The alternative I thought about is reading from the files directly, but then I would need to split them (250mb javascript max?) or stream them (good idea?).

Before I start writing code, I would like to understand how to approach this kind of massive (is it?) data most efficiently in Javascript. For now, everything is possible.

Thanks!
Jan

Comment: Have you considered using a database?

Comment: will do that, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would move your data to a database and server. I would personally make a RESTful api that modifies the data in a database that you would call to within your app.

Since you are writing in Javascript you could create a node server for a RESTful api, and store the data into a database like SQL or noSQL. Then take the data from the json file and put it into the database.

I would suggest looking into all the different database types and using a database to manipulate and hold your data. The big question is relational vs non-relational databases. Read this to get more information on this: http://jlamere.github.io/databases/

Comment: Thanks for the good answer! The data actually comes from our firebase, but reading from there would be too expensive. So I'll probably set up a mongodb on an amazon server and read the data from there.
How much data would be advisable to have in store, or should I use the db for all requests?
Also, is it useful to cache data and if, how could this applied here?
Thanks again!

Comment: @JanRuno It's best to keep all the update to date data in a database and to cache local data once a user calls for it. If a user modifies data client side, send an update to the server database. That can work the other way too, if data is altered on the server, then send the new information to the user so their cached data is up to date (sockets would be best here). When my app boots I get all the information from the server and connect to a socket using socket.io and when information is altered I have a stream to get the new info and send new info. It get's more complicated but that's a way.